# How can I simulate a Python shell most effectively and securely?

Tags: python, shell, numpy, pandas, javascript

For to offer interactive examples about data analysis, I'd like to embed an interactive python shell. It does not necessarily have to be a *real* Python shell. Users shall be given tasks that they can execute in the shell. This is similar to existing tutorials, as seen on, e.g., http://www.codecademy.org, but I'd like to work with libraries that those solutions do not offer, as far as I understood.

In order to get a real shell on the website, I think of two approaches:

- I found projects like http://www.repl.it, but it seems rather difficult to include the necessary libraries like SciPy, NumPy, and Pandas. In addition, user input has to be validated and I'm not sure whether that works with those shells I found.
- I could pipe the commands through a web applications to a Python installation on my server, but I'm scared of using `eval()` on foreign, arbitrary code. Is there a safe mode for Python? I found http://www.pypy.org. Although they offer a Python sandbox, unfortunately, they do not support the libraries I need.
- Alternatively, I thought of just embedding a "fake shell", which I build to copy the behaviour of the functions that I want to explain. Of course, this would result in more work, as I would have to write a fake interface, but for now it seems to be the only possibility.

I hope that this question is not too generic; I'm looking for either a good HTML/JS library that helps me put a fake shell on my website or a library/service/software that can embed a real Python shell with the required modules installed.

Comment: A python virtualenv might help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to run untrusted Python safely; Python's dynamic nature allows for too many ways to break through any protective layers you could care to think of.

Instead, run each session on a new virtual machine, properly locked down (firewalled, unprivileged user), which you shut down after a hard time limit. New sessions get a new, clean virtual machine.

This isolates you from any malicious code that might run and try to break out of a sandbox; a good virtual machine is hardware-isolated by the processor from the host OS, something a Python-only layer could never achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. A virtual machine would be isolated from the main system, of course. However, wouldn't it still be prone to abuse, as one would have system access via Python and could do anything in the internet? This question might reveal that I am new to the sandboxing topic :-)

Comment: @Tobias: Which is why I said you need to have the virtual machine firewalled.

Comment: If you say that it could technically be reasonable to spawn isolated virtual machines on a server when users start the course on my website, then I will investigate further, although this sounds quite complicated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tobias I'll just note that another option (free under some circumstances only), might be seeing if [Sphere Engine](https://ideone.com/sphere-engine) (what powers ideone) could be of use

Answer (score 3):

This process is sometimes called *sandboxing*.
You can find some [good information on the python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython)

There are basically three options available:

- machine-level mechanisms (such as a VM, as Martijn Pieters suggested)
- OS-level mechanisms (such as a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chroot) or [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux))
- custom interpreters, such as pypy ([which has sandboxing capabilities](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html), as you mentioned), or [Jython](http://jython.org/), where you may be able to use the Java security manager or applet mechanisms.

You may also want to check [Restricted Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython/), which is especially useful for very restricted environments, but security will depend on its configuration.

Ultimately, your choice of solution will depend on *what you want to restrict*:

- Filesystem access? Block everything, or allow certain directories?
- Network access, such as sockets?
- Arbitrary system calls?

Comment: Thank you. I would already be happy if only those commands needed for the course were executable, but the most important aspect is that (a) internet access is blocked, although the system has to communicate with the website, and (b) the system cannot be modified.

Comment: @Tobias If you're on linux, you may want to simply try running CPython with a custom SELinux policy then. Starting from a deny-all, you'll need to add exceptions to allow (read-only) access your libraries in the filesystem. You'll want to keep the website and the python process separate and communicate through a pipe, as you mentioned